# область видимости AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем доброго времени суток. 
У меня вопрос могу ли я изменить свойства $scope обычного контроллера из вне фреймворка? 
я использую socket io и приходящие данные мне нужно поместить допустим в $scope.accInfo.user_id. Как это сделать?

```html
var socket = io();
socket.on('new event', function (msg) {
  //msg - это сообщение нужно поместить в $scope.accInfo.user_id
})
    
var settAcc = angular.module('settAcc', [])

settAcc.controller('addApp', function($scope){
  $scope.accInfo = {
                      user_id: '' // сюда нужно поместить msg 
                    }     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так, наверное:

```js
var socket = io();

settAcc.controller('addApp', function($scope) {
  $scope.accInfo = {
    user_id: '' // сюда нужно поместить msg 
  };

  socket.on('new event', function (msg) {
    $scope.accInfo.user_id = msg;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
});
```

Comment: спасибо огромное всю голову изломал, а всего то надо было мне ранее добавить $scope.$apply();